# Sumif vs vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to either use vlookup or sumif to pull data from multiple excel sheet.The account numbers(some of them) are repeated twice so when I use vlookup its not pulling actual total. Example 140200 has two numbers, only pulling one.

1. Vlookup is not pulling all the account number total for example if acct number is 100100 is twice in one entity, its only picking one number.
2. I used sumif but its giving me - if use sumif+sumif+sumif.

I know how to use these formulas, what am I doing wrong.

ex:

```
=(IFERROR(SUMIF('Z:\Global Chart of Accounts\TB - 2015\[Flextecs LLC - Trial Balance 12-31-15.xlsx]12-31-15'!$A$2:$A$173,A2,'Z:\Global Chart of Accounts\TB - 2015\[Flextecs LLC - Trial Balance 12-31-15.xlsx]12-31-15'!$D$2:$D$173),0))+(SUMIF('[FTS LLC - Trial Balance 12-31-15.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$23,A2,'[FTS LLC - Trial Balance 12-31-15.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$2:$D$23))
```

I have tried both vlookup and sumif

[image]

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` is not a formula for summing and providing results. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: These are, by the looks of it, referenced closed workbooks. `SUMIF` will throw an [error](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-sumif-sumifs-function-e65ce689-978e-44b1-a649-160ed5f13b5a). I suggest you use `SUMPRODUCT` instead.

Comment: What your doing wrong for the most part is sloppy organization. Try collating the pertinent data and placing it within one workbook. Only then would you be able to have a formula that doesn't break when one workbook is closed.